# How should lists be cast to their conrecte implementations?

Tags: java

Let's suppose I'm using a library for which I don't know the source code. It has a method that returns a List, like so:

```
public List<SomeObj> getObjs() { ... }
```

I'm wondering if this is a good idea:

```
ArrayList<SomeObj> objs = (ArrayList<SomeObj>) getObjs();
```

If, for example, the concrete implementation of the List inside getObjs() is a `LinkedList` then wouldn't there be some kind of type discrepancy?

Comment: Yes, the cast would fail. Terribly. Why do you care about the concrete class?

Comment: Why don't you just define objs as a List ?

Comment: Doesn't this get rid of all advantages of coding to the implementation? Why bother coding to the implementation if you're just going to throw it out?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels It absolutely does, I was just interested in the repercussions of doing this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, it is not a good idea. You should always use the interface (`List`) to declare your list variable unless you for some reason need specific behaviour from `ArrayList`.
Also, if you do, you need to be really sure that the list returned is an `ArrayList`. In this case, the promised contract of `getObjs()` is only that the return type is some kind of `List`, so you shouldn't assume anything else. Even if the `List` returned now would be `ArrayList` , there is nothing preventing the implementer of `getObjs()` to later change the type of `List` returned, which would then break your code.

Comment: Or to add to the point, the method may even return different list implementations depending on input or result size (For example we have methods in our project that do return a special 'read-only-empty' list in some methods if the list would be empty).

Answer (score 4):

Cast to the return type defined by the API you are calling.

If it says it returns a `List<SomeObj>`, then that is. Don't try to retrieve the underlying type, because:

a) It can vary with new versions (or even between calls)

b) You do not need to know the implementing class for anything.

If you **need** an ArrayList, then do `new ArrayList<SomeObject)(getObjs());`

Answer (score 3):

The whole point of using interfaces (List) is to hide implementation details. Why do you want to cast it to specific implementation?

Answer (score 2):

You're correct. That is not a good idea. You need to use the interface form that it's returning.

Answer (score 1):

It would throw a ClassCastException if you downcasted to ArrayList when in fact it was a LinkedList.  Generally its never a good idea to downcast like this especially if you didn't write the code that returns the object you want to downcast.  Plus if you are using 3rd party libs like this they might change what they return you as they improve their code.  If you put downcasts like this in your code it might work today, but when you upgrade your libs it all of a sudden it breaks.  And it breaks at runtime not compile time so you won't know its broken until you run it.  This is an issue of you violating the contract the library has with you which only using a List interface.

Answer (score 1):

The *reason* why it returns a `List` is so that you don't have to care what it is underlying that interface.

The `List` interface simply declares the contract the object has to satisfy, and how you query it. The library author is at liberty in the future to pick an `ArrayList`,a `LinkedList`, or maybe a `LazyDatabasePopulatedList`. In fact you may get a different implementation at runtime depending on how the providing class has been implemented.

So long as you have a contract to adhere to, this buys you a lot of freedom. There's a lot to be said for only talking and providing interfaces, and dealing with concrete classes as little as possible.

Answer (score 1):

You should always use the interface in place of the `Handle`. That is the whole point of `OOP` Languages so that you can switch between any implementation later.

If you are casting to any concrete class, the compiler will warn you about a possibility of `Cast` Exception that may occur. You can use `SuppressWarning` if you are very much sure about the type.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a good idea because you don't know what implementation the method returns; if it's not an `ArrayList`, you'll get a `ClassCastException`. In fact, you should not be concerned with what exact implementation the method returns. Use the `List` interface instead.

If, for some reason, you absolutely need an `ArrayList`, then create your own `ArrayList` and initialize it with the `List` returned by the method:

```
ArrayList<SomeObj> myOwnList = new ArrayList(getObjs());
```

But don't do this, unless you *absolutely* need an `ArrayList` - because it's inefficient.

Comment: Are you suggesting an ArrayList is inefficient ?

Comment: @BrianAgnew No I guess he is suggesting that it is inefficient to create a new list from a fully functional list for no reason.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you do this:

```
List<SomeObj> objs = getObjs();
```

And then work with that list. If for some reason you really need a ArrayList, you can always do

```
ArrayList<SomeObj> arrayList = new ArrayList<SomeObj>();
arrayList.addAll(objs);
```

And work with that. This is not very efficient though.